# Rails 5 API integration tests don't work with jsonapi-resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest, json-api, jsonapi-resources

I can't test POST requests against my `jsonapi-resources` Rails 5.1 API.  Rails does not seem to allow me to customize request content types, or is doing it wrong.

`jsonapi-resources` version 0.9.0, edge Rails (I think it's 5.2 beta2)

So, this IntegrationTest code:

```
require 'test_helper'

class EventsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @event = events(:one)
  end

  test 'should get index' do
    get events_url, as: 'application/vnd.api+json'
    assert_response :success
  end

  test 'should create event' do
    assert_difference('Event.count') do
      post events_url, params: {
        data: {
          type: 'events',
          attributes: {
            name: @event.name,
            body: @event.body
          }
        }
      },
      as: :api_json
    end
    assert_response 201
  end

end
```

...produces this error:

```
$ bin/rails test
...

Failure:
EventsControllerTest#test_should_create_event [/Users/aljabear/Projects/visualist/test/controllers/events_controller_test.rb:26]:
...
```

The GET request works fine.  The POST request is borked.  Printing out the @request.body after the POST request gives this clue:

```
{
 "errors":[
    {"title":"Bad Request",
     "detail":"765: unexpected token at 'data[type]=events\u0026data[attributes][name]=Book+1\u0026data[attributes][body]=This+is+body+text.'",
     "code":"400",
     "status":"400"
    }
 ]
}
```

So, clearly the `:api_json` content type is not being respected by Rails;
 I guess it's instead spitting out form URL encoded.

if I do this instead, and print the result:

```
...
as: :json,
headers: {
  'Content-type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
}
...
```

I get the following, showing that `jsonapi-resources` is behaving properly (just very strictly); when I use `as: :json`, Rails correctly formats things as `json`, just not when I do `:api_json`.

```
{
 "errors":[{
    "title":"Not acceptable",
    "detail":"All requests must use the 'application/vnd.api+json' Accept without media type parameters. This request specified 'application/json'.",
    "code":"406",
    "status":"406"
  }]
}
```

Is Rails just not bothering to convert the MIME type as requested?  Or is this just a serialization issue?  How can I force it to do it?  Thanks... any clues are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm successfully using code like the following:

```
test 'should create event' do
  assert_difference('Event.count') do
    post events_url, params: {
      data: {
        type: 'events',
        attributes: {
          name: @event.name,
          body: @event.body
        }
      }
    },
    as: :json,
    headers: {
      'Accept' => JSONAPI::MEDIA_TYPE,
      'Content-Type' => JSONAPI::MEDIA_TYPE
    }
  end
  assert_response :created
end
```

I have a project on [GitHub](https://github.com/sapientpants/ember-cli-rails-todomvc) that you can look at to see my code.

Comment: giving you the vote on this, although haven't tested it myself; I moved on to [Fast JsonAPI](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi) instead

Answer (score 0):

> Is Rails just not bothering to convert the MIME type as requested? Or is this just a serialization issue? How can I force it to do it?

tl;dr: Yes, yes and `as_json` :)

tests are a subset of rails functionality - they don't go through the full rails stack (and thus does no conversions based on MIME type).

Yes, I think so - ie you need to serialize it so that rails can unserialize it.

```
Try running `as_json` on your data... eg

  test 'should create event' do
    assert_difference('Event.count') do
      post events_url, params: {
        data: {
          type: 'events',
          attributes: {
            name: @event.name,
            body: @event.body
          }
        }.as_json
      },
      as: :api_json
    end
    assert_response 201
  end
```

or similar on your actual data... ie... if you're telling Rails to expect json... then pass it json? :D